# How can I get the href value from counted links with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Source Code:

```
<a href="http://asd.com/123/qwe">1</a>
<a href="http://asd.net/asd">2</a>
<a href="http://123.com">3</a>
<a href="http://www.a1s2d3.com">4</a>
<a href="http://www.q1w2e3.com">5</a>
<a href="http://bnm.org/questions/">6</a><br /><br />

<span id="element"></span>
```

jQuery Code

```
var total = $('a').size();
$('#element').text(total);
```

I get the size of a tags. But I cant get the href value of all a tags. How can I write the the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
 $('#element').text(function(){
   return $('a').map(function(){ return this.href }).get().join(","); 
 });
```

Basically

```
var arrOfLinks = $('a').map(function(){ return this.href }).get();
```

will give you array of links.

Comment: Amit Joki code works here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MtCGb/. Remember you need to include the JQuery library.